# <table> for layouts is evil right?

Tags: html, layout

Just found out that this site uses tables for layouts. Does anyone find this disturbing considering the nature of the site? I really don't know what to believe anymore :-)

http://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: Given that the tables vs. divs/css debate still rages on, I can't imagine this 'question' will result in anything but a flamewar.

Comment: This site is about programming not design.  If A List Apart starts using a table-based layout you can start to worry.

Comment: Bill, where does programming start and design end?

Comment: @Craig: When you stop using a programming language. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More eloquent people than I have made some compelling arguments to the contrary.  Here's some recent (because that's important when it comes to browser technology) essays to check out:

- http://iamelgringo.blogspot.com/2009/02/tables-vs-css-css-trolls-begone.html
- http://www.flownet.com/ron/css-rant.html
- http://thinkvitamin.com/features/css/tables-the-next-evolution-in-css-layout/

Comment: Google uses tables for layout!!!!!!!!!!! Dam, why do I bother listening to 'professional' web designers anyway?

Comment: Thats it! I'm using tables from now on :-) Nice links Daniel

Comment: Google also (supposedly, sometimes, depending on their algorithm at the moment) penalizes people who aren't Google who use tables for layout.

Comment: And neither Google's nor StackOverflow's pages validate. In Google's case because it serves tag soup for reasons best known to itself, and in SO's case mostly because Jeff Atwood doesn't know (or doesn't care) that the alt attribute is required for images in strict HTML 4. When you have advertisers knocking down your door, you can ignore the rules too...

Answer (score 5):

Tables are good for displaying data that normally fits...in a table.  Think a list of Names with associated attributes.

Tables are evil for layout.  Layout should be done via CSS.

Separation of data and display is an important concept in all of computer science.

Comment: True, but as Daniel pointed out, tables can be used for layouts. I think its more a case of what the more popular opinion is between tables and CSS. I've always been a firm believer in CSS, however, this is only because I've been going off what I read, not being able to think for myself.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are using the table for. And how many tables you are using.

If you are using the table to display tabular data, it is the best. Otherwise, use the modern stuff.

There are times where it is OK to violate purity.

Comment: I just find it strange that a site teaching HTML uses tables for layout. Amusing.

Comment: Actually, I was defending SO, this page only had 2 tables when I Sourced it 4 hours ago (now it has more, they appear to use tables for comments).  Now I went to w3schools.com, and horror or horrors!

Answer (score 1):

I think this page is the most ironic: An [introduction to CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp) (completely built in tables). It doesn't fill you with much confidence...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I would steer clear of it. Tables should be reserved for tabulated data :) Try to layout sites using div's and CSS

Comment: I'd add the caveat that <div>s *can* be almost as "evil" as tables. Only use them when they're semantic (i.e add structure to the site) or when there's absolutely no other way to get the effect you're trying for.