# Can we use tables to design a form?

Tags: html, css

While I was designing a form, I found that designing a form using tables can be much easier and simpler instead of using CSS.

But, is this a good technique to use?

Will it affect the flexibility of the website later?

Comment: some reasons why it isnt such a good idea - http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/159157-the-evil-of-tables/

Comment: possible duplicate of [<table> for layouts is evil right?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890850/table-for-layouts-is-evil-right)

Comment: I think these two links will help you. [This is Why You Should Use Tables for Forms Layout](http://andrewtokeley.net/archive/2007/09/15/this-is-why-you-should-use-tables-for-forms-layout.aspx) - [Better UI Design: Proper Use of Tables](http://www.noupe.com/how-tos/better-ui-design-proper-use-of-tables.html)

Answer (score 6):

HTML is about structure, CSS about design. So if your form semantically is a table, because you have key/value pairs, like "name", "surname", "email", etc. along with the user entered value, simply use a table as structure and design it using CSS.

Comment: Additionally, the use of proper <label> tags for your form will increase the accessability of your form.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any problems using tables with forms. Using tables to design a website is a bad idea, though.

If you build the table the right way, I don't see why it would make the site non flexible.

Answer (score -1):

Think about your customer. Are they likely to want to 'tweak' your design over and over either during development or afterwards ?

If so then choose the table-less route using `<div>`s or `<ul><li>`. It maybe a bit tougher to get right in the first place but  - arguably - much easier to adapt down the line.